# Pretty search URLs in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using [Nice Search](http://wordpress.org/plugins/nice-search/) to redirect `?s=query` searches to `/search/query` in WordPress:

```
function pretty_search_redirect() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    if ( !isset( $wp_rewrite ) || !is_object( $wp_rewrite ) || !$wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() )
        return;

    $search_base = $wp_rewrite->search_base;
    if ( is_search() && !is_admin() && strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/{$search_base}/" ) === false ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/{$search_base}/" . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) ) );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'pretty_search_redirect' );
```

This works great. Thanks to the author of the Nice Search plugin!

My aim now is to do the same thing for my user search. I'm trying to redirect `/people/?q=query` to `/people/query`.

**Here is my people search form:**

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="/people/"> 
    <input type="search" value="" name="q" title="Search" />    
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

**And here is my search query:**

```
// get the search query
$search = ( isset( $_GET["q"] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_GET["q"] ) : false;

// get the page number
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// items to display per page
$display = 1;

// calculate the offset
$offset = ( $paged - 1 ) * $display;

$args = array(
    'role'     => 'Author',
    'search' => '*' . $search . '*',
    'number' => $display,
    'offset' => $offset,
    'count_total' => true
);

$users = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

How can I modify the Nice Search code to make it work for my people search? I'd like my people search URLs to take the form `/people/query`

Comment: Where is your search query code, exactly? In a Page Template? Or somewhere else?

Comment: I've set up a page via the WP dashboard, and called it 'People' so I've put my query code in `wp-content/themes/mytheme/page-people.php`. My search form is in `header.php`. I can access the People page on the front end using `example.com/people`